# Determine encoding of date (or datetime) using 4 bytes

Tags: datetime, encoding, reverse-engineering

Need some help to determine how is this date/time being encoded.

I've tried different methods, unixtime, little endian, big endian, can't figure it out.

Here are some examples (known date only):

> 20 94 9D 21 = 29-12-2016
>
> C7 91 9E 21 = 30-12-2016
>
> AD 6A 72 22 ~ around 24-03-2017

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying that 20 94 9D 21 = 29-12-2016 *and some unknown time* or that there is no time component?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I didn't took notes of the exact time. Sorry.

Comment: I suspect the first two bytes are the time (e,g, 0x9420) and the second two bytes (e.g. 0x219D) are the date. What program are these numbers coming from? Would 1999-02-15 be significant to that program? That might be a massive clue to someone.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Mifare card, written each time the card is used. That's why I have multiple examples but not the correct date for all of them.

Answer (score 2):

It would be very helpful to have a midpoint time (do you have any more examples?), but it appears to be *approximately* a half-second per integer value there.

```
Sample 1: 0x219d9420 -> 563,975,200 (decimal)
Sample 2: 0x219e91c7 -> 564,040,135 (decimal)
Sample 3: 0x22726aad -> 577,923,757 (decimal)

Timestamp 1: 29-12-2016 -> 1482969600 (unixtime)
Timestamp 2: 30-12-2016 -> 1483056000 (unixtime)
Timestamp 3: 24-03-2017 -> 1490313600 (unixtime)
```

The difference between sample 3 and sample 1/2 definitely increases somewhat proportionally to the distance between timestamp 3 and timestamps 1/2, but because 1/2 are so close together (and uncertain), it's really difficult to say for certain.

Overall, you end up with 7,344,000 seconds passed while 13,948,557 mystery timestamps passed, which is pretty close (given the uncertainty in the given dates) to 2 mystery-timestamps per second.  This would put a start time about 9.4 years before the first timestamp, around Aug 2, 2007.

Comment: In my attempt(s), I reversed the four hex elements but didn't reverse the elements themselves. Good catch!

Comment: I have more hex examples, but not the dates.

Comment: @ArtHare I have a new sample: 53A5D522 - 2017-06-27 around 18:55

Comment: Yeah that's a weird timestamp system, if it is in fact a timestamp.  Your new one is 1498521600 unixtime, with a "value" of 584426835.  It continues to grow with time, but not as fast per day as the 3rd sample did over the 1st and 2nd sample.